# Why is my character deformed when moving or rotating a bone?

Tags: modeling, armature

[When I was testing the movement of the bones of the whole body I moved the head bone, I rotated it on the X axis to be exact, and when I rotated it the head of the character looked as if it had lengthened in the back and it also looked like as if the top of the head had been flattened, what can I do so it won´t happen again?[image: ][1]]

Comment: first select all the vertices of your head in Edit mode, then go into the Object Data panel > Vertex Groups, and in the dropdown menu on the right of the list, choose Remove From All Groups, and weight paint the head

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of weight do you recommend using to improve this situation of the character's head?       By "What kind of weight" I mean that maybe I should use 0.500 of weight or 1.000 of weight while weight painting the head

Comment: If the head bone is the only one that is supposed to control the head mesh, it doesn't matter the weight, you can choose 1

Comment: Thanks, it kind of worked with the head, I say kind of because it still keeps enlarging a bit, but not too much as it was in the beginning, but now I have another problem, it´s kind of the same situation, but it happens with the arms an the legs, do you recommend using the weight paint like I did with the head?       I´ll leave two links here so you can click on them and you can take a look at the pictures of how the leg of my character is deforming :   https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKnHy.png                                         
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzSeS.png

Comment: And I also left a link to an image where the weight paint is shown, so you can tell me if it is good how I weight painted the leg

Comment: if you have the same problem with other parts of your object you will fix it the same way, but maybe share your file here (copy paste the link it will give in the URL field): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I´m sorry if I make a lot of questions about how to solve the problem I have about my model, but I´m a beginner, I´ve been using Blender for just 2 weeks, but anyway here is the link to my Blender file : https://pasteall.org/media/a/7/a78cac3ce9f6590e1259feac7a48248c.blend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in *Object* mode, select your armature, open the *N* panel and in *Item > Transform > Scale*, see the values, you've scaled your armature on Z, it explains why it's so deformed. To bring it back to a 1:1:1 scale press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*. You'll also need to select the arms and go in the *Child Of* constraint and click on *Set Inverse* (if you plan to keep these constraints, not sure if it's useful compared to a simple parentage though). If you want to scale your bones, do it in *Edit* mode.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for helping me, it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried weightpaining these areas by hand?
You could also try too move the neck bone a bit up and apply a fresh automatic weight paint.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).